# Define last bar of distribution plot as more than all values before

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr, distribution

I wan to plot the distribution of the overall number of wins of a player. I would like to have the last section of the x-axis as a "more than the values before" category.

Example data:

```
game_data <- data.frame(player = c(1,2,3,4,5, 6), n_wins = c(1,8,2,3,6,4))

game_data
  player n_wins
1      1      1
2      2      8
3      3      2
4      4      3
5      5      6
6      6      4
6      6      4
```

The following code creates a category "NA", but I want it to be 5+ (= more than 5 wins).

```
game_data %>% group_by(player) %>% summarise(allwins = sum(n_wins)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cut(allwins, breaks = seq(1,6, by = 1)), include.lowest=TRUE)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  labs(title="Distribution of Wins", subtitle="", y="Fraction of Players", x="Number of Wins")
```

[image: Distribution Plot]

I do not only want to change the label, I want it to automatically create the last category.

Comment: The NA showing up comes from the value n_wins==1 (player 1). If you want it included in the first bin, just add argument `include.lowest=TRUE` to `cut(...)`

Comment: Yes, you're right. My example was bad. I wanted to have a few values > 6 and wanted to have a category 6+ for these. I will fix the example.

Comment: you can use `Inf` as the highest break: `cut(-1:8, breaks=c(-Inf, 1:5, Inf))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following by including +Inf as a break, note that you have no values that are 5, so you need to add a drop=FALSE with scale_x_discrete:

```
set.seed(100)
game_data <- data.frame(player = c(1,2,3,4,5, 6), n_wins = c(1,8,2,3,6,4))
BR = c(0:5,+Inf)

game_data %>% 
group_by(player) %>% summarise(allwins = sum(n_wins)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cut(allwins, breaks = BR,labels=c(1:5,"5+")))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  labs(title="Distribution of Wins", subtitle="", 
y="Fraction of Players", x="Number of Wins")+
scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

Maybe a small comment, why do you need to summarize the data?

Comment: You're right, I do not need to summarize here.
On my dataset, I need to define bigger breaks, then I do not know how to apply your solution. Let's say the number of wins are very high and I need breaks = seq(1,500, by = 100)). How can I use Inf here?

Comment: Following that example above, you do BR = c(seq(1,500, by = 100),+Inf). And cut using this. You then have to decide what to name your bins, maybe labels=c((seq(1,500, by =100),"500+")